# C : como asignar char* a const char* const*

Tags: c, string

Una funcion me devuelve cierto numero de cadenas (`uint_32 extensions_count`) y tengo que asignar cada una de ellas en `const char* const* extensions`.
Las cadenas están en esta estructura:

```
typedef struct VkExtensionProperties {
    char        extensionName[VK_MAX_EXTENSION_NAME_SIZE];
    uint32_t    specVersion;
} VkExtensionProperties;
```

el valor de `extensions_count` varía en torno a 4 (obtenido previamente) y las cadenas se almacenan en `available_extensions`

```
VkExtensionProperties * available_extensions=(VkExtensionProperties*)malloc(sizeof(VkExtensionProperties) * extensions_count );
vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(NULL, &extensions_count, available_extensions )
```

La duda es como asignar las cadenas en `available_extensions` a `extensions` (solo C).

```
const char* extensions[extensions_count];

for(size_t i=0;i < extensions_count; i++){
if(strcmp(VK_KHR_PLATFORM_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME,available_extensions[i].extensionName) == 0){
        for(size_t j=0;j < extensions_count; j++){
            //Aqui la duda
            //extensions[j] = available_extensions[j].extensionName;
        }
        printf("Extension name found\n%s\n",available_extensions[i].extensionName);
        break;
    }
}
```

Lo que normalmente obtengo es violación de segmento y no paso de ahí. Si es posible con `strcpy`, la verdad no se como usarlo en este caso en particular.
De antemano gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Si el destino es constante ¿por qué deseas escribir en el mismo? ¿no significa entonces que **no es constante**?

Answer (score 3):

La copia la tenes que hacer si o si con strcpy:

```
char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src)
```

Donde `dest` es el puntero al arreglo destino en donde se copiará el string y `src` es el string a ser copiado.

Te está dando violación de segmento porque no estas alocando memoria para las cadenas.

> const char* extensions[extensions_count];

Es un arreglo de punteros de longitud `extensions_count`. Te falta alocar memoria para cada puntero de cada posición. Por ejemplo.

```
extensions[i] = malloc(N * sizeof(char));
```

Donde `N` es la longitud de tu cadena.

Una vez que hayas reservado la memoria ya podes hacer el `strcpy()`.

```
strcpy(extensions[i], "Tu string");
```

Comment: Podrias por favor agregar el prototipo de la funcion aca? Siempre preferimos eso porque los links se pueden caer. Igual la respuesta es correcta asi que +1

Comment: @gbianchi listo. Gracias por la corrección.

Answer (score 0):

```
const char* extensions[extensions_count];
```

Ahí estás declarando un array de punteros... pero esos punteros no apuntan a ninguna parte... están sin inicializar.

Con esto en mente solo tienes dos opciones:

1. Que estos punteros apunten a la cadena que corresponda. Nota que en este caso tienes dos punteros apuntando a la misma cadena (cuidado con las modificaciones):

   ```
   for(size_t j=0; j < extensions_count; j++)
     extensions[j] = available_extensions[j].extensionName;
   ```
2. Inicializar los punteros (que cada uno apunte a un buffer propio) y copiar las cadenas. En este caso tendrás dos copias independientes de cada cadena:

   ```
   // opcion 1
   for(size_t j=0; j < extensions_count; j++)
     extensions[j] = strdup(available_extensions[j].extensionName);


   // opcion 2
   for(size_t j=0; j < extensions_count; j++)
   {
     extensions[j] = malloc(strlen(available_extensions[j].extensionName));
     strcpy(extensions[j],available_extensions[j].extensionName);
   }

   // ...

   for(size_t j=0; j < extensions_count; j++)
     free(extensions[j]);
   ```

¿El problema que puedes encontrarte? Varios:

- Que ese elemento aparentemente tonto que es `const` puede hacer que los elementos se almacenen en una posición especial de la memoria de solo lectura y cualquier intento de modificación desemboca en un error porque el Sistema Operativo está matando tu proceso para evitar la corrupción de la memoria. También puede suceder que el compilador te muestre advertencias si intentas modificar el contenido constante. Si este es el origen del problema quizás lo más sensato entonces sea quitar `const`:

  ```
  char* extensions[extensions_count];
  ```
- Deberías garantizar que `extensions_count` es mayor que cero. Al binario en C no le suelen gustar los arrays de longitud 0.

Por otro lado, dices que obtienes una violación de segmento... pero no dónde se está produciendo. Quizás el verdadero origen del problema está en otra parte del código (aunque se manifieste en esta sección del código).

A modo de bonus, dejo una pequeña guía para entender el significado de `const` en función de dónde se encuentre:

- `char*`: Puntero por defecto. **Nada es constante** y puedes jugar libremente tanto con el puntero como con la memoria apuntada.
- `const char*`: un puntero **no constante** apunta a una cadena **constante**. El puntero puede apuntar a donde te de la gana pero no deberías intentar modificar su contenido.
- `char* const`: El puntero es **constante**. No deberías intentar modificar la dirección a la que apunta. El contenido apuntado si puede ser modificado.
- `const char* const`: **Todo es constante**, tanto el puntero como la memoria apuntada.